# Protractor resolves promises with Chrome, but not Phantom

Tags: protractor, phantomjs

When running end to end tests with Protractor, I'm seeing promises in my tests being resolved when run with Chrome. But when run with Phantom, the callbacks are never executed, and the test eventually times out with the message `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

My **protractor.config.js** file looks like:

```
exports.config = {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  suites: {
    // ...
  },
  directConnect: !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'CI'),
  exclude: [],
  multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'CI' ? 'phantomjs' : 'chrome',
    'phantomjs.cli.args': ['--web-security=false',
      '--ignore-ssl-errors=true'
    ]
  }],
  allScriptsTimeout: 110000,
  getPageTimeout: 100000,
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: false,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: false,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 400000,
    print: function() {}
  },
}
```

With this configuration, a test like the following will execute its callback for Chrome, but not for Phantom:

```
let targetUrl = '/foo';
it ('should resolve the route properly', function (done) {
  browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
      console.log("****"); // This is printed in Chrome, but not Phantom
      expect(url).toContain(targetUrl);
      done();
})});
```

**Node Modules Versions**

Protractor: 5.0.0
Phantom: 4.0.0
PhantomJS 2.1.7
PhantomJS-prebuilt: 2.1.14
Webdriver Manager (inside Protractor): 11.1.1

Any ideas?

Comment: phantomjs is no longer officially supported, it was abandoned in favor of headless chrome.  I would suggest switching to that.

Comment: I've been thinking about it, but there may be issues with getting Chrome installed on our Jenkins server. (The docs for headless-chrome say Chrome needs to be installed separately, it isn't included.) So while working on that, I'd like to still continue to work on trying to get Phantom working, just in case getting Chrome installed falls through.